# Нельзя оставить отзывы в некоторых статьях WordPress

Tags: wordpress

Суть вопроса такова: нельзя оставить отзывы именно в некоторых статьях на сайте под WordPress, на всех остальных статьях комментарии оставляются, что делать-уже ума не приложу, возможно, проблема в каком-то условии, но заметил вот что: вновь созданные темы так же не имеют возможности оставления отзывов, возможно, это началось с какой-то даты...только вот какое условие...А еще я заметил одну такую вещь, что поле отзывов пропадает, когда отключаешь плагин Advanced Custom Fields PRO

Comment: Возможно на вашем сайте отзывы организованны через ACF (довольно полезный плагин), а насчет невозможности оставлять отзывы, это уже нужно лезть внутрь, можете написать в личку, помогу.

Answer (score 0):

Возможно при создании статей вы просто запрещаете комментирование записи. Проверьте, что на странице редактирования статьи ниже редактора текста в блоке управления обсуждениями, в поле "Разрешить комментарии" стоит галочка. Если нет - поставьте.

[image: обсуждение, разрешить комментарии]

Если блока управления обсуждениями не видно, включите его в настройках отображения (правый верхний угол - кликнуть по "настройки экрана", выбрать пункт "Обсуждение")

Comment: Там все намного сложнее, у некоторых статей $comments = пустому массиву

Comment: @lazyproger в таком случае автору вопроса стоит уточнить все важные детали, а не выдавать их порциями